# SSL Certificate Verification Error Airflow S3

Tags: airflow

I'm getting the following error when I run my pipeline and writing the log to S3.

Airflow version: 1.10.14

I have defined the s3_conn in Airflow Web UI together with the Key id and secret code as well.

In airflow.cfg, I have the following entries:

```
    base_log_folder = /root/airflow/logs
    
    # Airflow can store logs remotely in AWS S3, Google Cloud Storage or Elastic Search.
    # Set this to True if you want to enable remote logging.
    remote_logging = True
    
    # Users must supply an Airflow connection id that provides access to the storage
    # location.
    remote_log_conn_id = s3_conn
    remote_base_log_folder = s3://airflow-s3-buck2/test/
    encrypt_s3_logs = False
    logging_config_class = log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG
```

Here's my log_config.py:

```
import os

from airflow import configuration as conf

# TODO: Logging format and level should be configured
# in this file instead of from airflow.cfg. Currently
# there are other log format and level configurations in
# settings.py and cli.py. Please see AIRFLOW-1455.

LOG_LEVEL = conf.get('core', 'LOGGING_LEVEL').upper()
LOG_FORMAT = conf.get('core', 'log_format')

BASE_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('core', 'remote_base_log_folder')
PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('scheduler', 'child_process_log_directory')

FILENAME_TEMPLATE = '{{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log'
PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE = '{{ filename }}.log'

LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'airflow.task': {
            'format': LOG_FORMAT,
        },
        'airflow.processor': {
            'format': LOG_FORMAT,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.task',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
        },
        's3.task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.s3_task_handler.S3TaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.task',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            's3_log_folder': BASE_LOG_FOLDER,
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
        'file.task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.task',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
        'file.processor': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_processor_handler.FileProcessorHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.processor',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER),
            'filename_template': PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        }
        # When using s3 or gcs, provide a customized LOGGING_CONFIG
        # in airflow_local_settings within your PYTHONPATH, see UPDATING.md
        # for details
        # 's3.task': {
        #     'class': 'airflow.utils.log.s3_task_handler.S3TaskHandler',
        #     'formatter': 'airflow.task',
        #     'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
        #     's3_log_folder': S3_LOG_FOLDER,
        #     'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        # },
        # 'gcs.task': {
        #     'class': 'airflow.utils.log.gcs_task_handler.GCSTaskHandler',
        #     'formatter': 'airflow.task',
        #     'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
        #     'gcs_log_folder': GCS_LOG_FOLDER,
        #     'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        # },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL
        },
        'airflow': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'airflow.processor': {
            'handlers': ['file.processor'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'airflow.task': {
            'handlers': ['s3.task'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'airflow.task_runner': {
            'handlers': ['s3.task'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Error (in Scheduler log)

```
botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://airflow-s3-buck2.s3.amazonaws.com/test/s3_dag_test/bash_test/2016-11-01T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00/1.log *[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain* (_ssl.c:1124)
```

Any advice on how to fix he SSL Certification issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue yo are having is due to certificate not being trusted by your server because you are most likely using custom S3 provider. You will need to add this certificate to your CA certificates. If you have proper access to do it, please read this:

https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ca-certificates/update-ca-certificates.8.en.html

You will just put file into /usr/share/ca-certificates and run update-ca-certificates.

Assuming you are using official docker image/debian.

However, if you are indeed using docker image in Kubernetes. Then I could not come up with the proper solution outside of embedding certificate into image, as container is run by non-root, and Airflow code does not provide any 'extra' setting to mark it as trusted CA. Plus Boto3 also does not provide any setting that could be used without actually modifying code in Airflow, because an Endpoint setting is not part of ENV variables nor part of config files.